# .htaccess - Rewrite a request to one directory before the request is handled by that directory?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, .htaccess

I'm trying to exclude all BUT one directory from a rewrite rule.  I want the request to be handled by the index.php file in the root directory which will then include the subdirectory's index.php file as part of a script after wrapping it with it's own code.

This is a really strange problem, since I'm trying to wrap Drupal within a Wordpress installation so that the existing site structure can stay put, and I can use a custom template to wrap the drupal output in a slightly customized wordpress theme.

If anybody has any idea how I can do this, I would be very very thankful.

htaccess files seem like arcane arts.  Nobody seems to really get them that well, and I am no exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(drupal_directory|robots\.txt) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The ! will exclude drupal_directory and robots.txt etc...

Comment: I think this is the exact opposite of what I'm trying to do... I want the drupal directory to be included in the rewrite rule so that drupal's index.php is not directly called.  It's hard to explain why...

Comment: Oh, sorry then.  If you remove the ! then only the things listed will be sent to index.php.